# zend expressive + doctrine custom types

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, enums, mezzio

I'm trying to map a custom type to a string. Here's my entity definition:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", columnDefinition="my_type_enum", nullable=false)
 */
```

But when I try to create migration (migration:diff) this is the output

[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
      Unknown database type `my_type_enum` requested, `Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSQL92Platform` may not suppo
      rt it.

Seems I need to map my custom type `my_type_enum` to a string using `mapping_types`, but where in Zend Expressive? It's seems my configuration is ignored

```
...
     'doctrine' => [
       'dbal' => [
         'mapping_types' => [
           'my_type_enum' => 'string'
         ]
       ]
     ]
...
```

Answer (score 3):

zend-expressive itself doesn't have doctrine support build in. It depends on the doctrine module and its factory that you are using. The factory starts the doctrine service with the config. So I would look inside the doctrine factory to figure out how and if it supports custom mapping types.

In case yours doesn't support it, you can use [container-interop-doctrine](https://github.com/DASPRiD/container-interop-doctrine). It has support for this [built in](https://github.com/DASPRiD/container-interop-doctrine/blob/master/example/full-config.php) it seems (haven't tried it myself):

```
<?php
return [
    'doctrine' => [
        // ...
        'connection' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'driver_class' => \Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver::class,
                'wrapper_class' => null,
                'pdo' => null,
                'configuration' => 'orm_default', 
                'event_manager' => 'orm_default', 
                'params' => [],
                'doctrine_mapping_types' => [], // <-----
                'doctrine_commented_types' => [],
            ],
        ],
        'types' = [
            'typename' => Type::class,
        ], // <-----
    ],
];
```

Comment: +1 for https://github.com/DASPRiD/container-interop-doctrine We use it, and like it a lot. DASPRiD is a reliable architect and consistent maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to create your custom type that extends doctrine DBAL type:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException;

class MyType extends Type
{
    const MYTYPE = 'mytype';

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        return 'mytype';
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        // convert your type to php value
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        // convert your type to database value
    }
}
```

Recently I integrated a value object as a doctrine type, so you can take a look how your new type should look like: [PostcodeType](https://github.com/vasildakov/postcode-doctrine/blob/master/src/PostcodeType.php)

The next step is to register the new type, let say in your doctrine bootstrap or EntityManagerFactory:

```
<?php // ./src/Container/EntityManagerFactory.php

if (!\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::hasType("mytype")) {
    \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType('mytype', 'Your\Namespace\MyType');
    $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('mytype', 'mytype');
}

return $em;
```

Finally you have registered your new type and you can use it:

```
/**
 * @var \Your\Namespace\MyType
 * @Column(type="mytype")
 */
protected $param;
```